# Add toggle to an icon in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is an icon (caret in this case) which triggers a function call when is clicked. It must trigger the function only if `values.numerOfValues > 0`

```
<td>   
 <span >{{values.numerOfValues}} 
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down" ng-click="values.numerOfValues > 0 && $ctrl.myFunction(values.ids)">
        </i>
    </span>
</td>
```

The above part works well.

The problem comes up when I want to add a toggle menu. I don't want the function to be called when the icon is clicked, I want instead that when it is clicked to open a toggle with an option and only when the option is clicked to make the call.

I managed to make that functionality like this:

```
<div class="yp-split-button" uib-dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="yp-action-btn" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem" ng-click="$ctrl.myFunction(values.ids)"><a>Disable All</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The toggle is opened when the button inside the red circle is clicked. My goal is to move this functionality to the button inside the green circle.

There is the functionality I talked about at the beginning. It calls directly the function without opening the toggle.

How can I move the functionality of the button to the caret?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
<td>
    <div class="dropdown enable-status" uib-dropdown>
        <span >{{values.numerOfValues}}</span>
        <span ng-disabled="!values.numerOfValues" uib-dropdown-toggle><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
            <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a ng-click="$ctrl.myFunction(values.ids)">Disable all</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("yp-action-btn")[0].onclick = (function(){
  toggle(dropdown)
})


function toggle(id){ 
 if (id.classList[0] === "hidden"){
    id.classList = "unhidden"
  }
  else {
    id.classList = "hidden"
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
.unhidden {display: block}
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" class="yp-action-btn">Toggle
    </button>
    <ul class="hidden" id="dropdown">
        <li>
        <a onclick="alert()">Disable All</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```